# Cairo can not find OpenGL ES 2.0 headers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, make, opengl, mesa, cairo

I am trying to compile Cairo 1.16.0, but it fails, giving me the following errors:

```
checking for cairo's OpenGLESv2 surface backend feature... 
checking for glesv2... no
checking GLES2/gl2.h usability... no
checking GLES2/gl2.h presence... no
checking for GLES2/gl2.h... no
checking whether cairo's OpenGLESv2 surface backend feature could be enabled... no (glesv2.pc nor OpenGL ES 2.0 headers not found)
configure: error:  OpenGLESv2 surface backend feature could not be enabled
package/pkg-generic.mk:228: recipe for target '/home/nmcain/Desktop/buildroot/output/build/cairo-1.16.0/.stamp_configured' failed.
```

I have installed nearly every package remotely related to Opengl, but it still won't compile. How can I fix this?

Comment: ... does "nearly every package" include `libgles2-mesa-dev`?

Comment: @steeldriver It does. I have seen this same issue posted around after googling it a bit, however not with Cairo.

Comment: That's odd - it appears to work for me (also on 18.04). How exactly did you obtain and configure the source?

Comment: @steeldriver I am using buildroot